# Как использовать несколько Таймеров последовательно?

Tags: java, android

Работаю над приложением которое сначало бы запускало `Voice recognition`, затем, после 5 секунд `MediaPlayer`. Использую Taimer для реализации `Voice recognition` (пример ниже) перезапускает `Voice recognition` через 5 секунд. Но не могу добавить ещё один `Timer` для запуска `MediaPlayer`, чтобы он запускался через 5 сек после запуска `Voice recognition`. Как добавить ещё один `Taimer`? А так же установить количество перезапусков?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
}
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> results;
            results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            TextView speechText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String str="";
            for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){
                str+= results.get(i);
            }               
                speechText.setText(str);         
        }


Timer timer2 = new Timer();
            timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MediaPlayer voice = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.inter);
                    voice.start();
                    voice.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer voice) {
                            voice.release();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 10000);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Вам надо в onActivityResult новый таймер запустить? В этом проблема?

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает onActivityResult ? Как я понял после него, получающего результат обработки голоса вам и надо?..

Comment: Я плохо вашу идею понял, но, наверное, вам надо всего раз запустить первый тамер, обработать голос, запустить таймер с медиаПлеером и в его окончании запустить заново первый таймер?...

Comment: Совершенно верно!

Comment: Ну, значит надо в onCompletion первый таймер заново настроить и изначально его не повторяющимся сделать.

Comment: Вы не могли бы эту часть кода в ответе написать? Не могу понять, как это реализовать.

Comment: С кодом не помогу - ни разу не пробовал подобное, но принцип в ответе описал. Вы можете опробовать и дополнить через редактирование мой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Первый таймер надо запустить один раз методом `schedule` вместо `scheduleAtFixedRate`, коий запускает цикл из таймеров.
2. В onActivityResult запустить `MediaPlayer`, присвоить ему слушатель окончания проигрывания (setOnCompletionListener)
3. В его методе `onCompletion()` создать новый таймер-аналог таймера из п1

Comment: Спасибо, работает! + 1 к карме! Юрий, я убрал время повторения и он у меня сейчас  последовательно прогоняет бесконечным циклом плеер и голос, как задать количество повторений? предположим, через 5 прогонов он должен остановиться.

Comment: Просто заведите в активити переменную счетчик и перед запуском таймера проверяйте что она меньше 5. В он комплит увеличивайте на 1